# After rsync no files exist

Tags: rsync, file-copy, fat

From my Ubuntu server I used rsync to copy all my data to my USB drive (FAT). After copying the data (it needed quite a while to copy so I guess the copying did happen) I deleted it from the server.

But now I cannot find the data on the USB drive - only all the folders exist.

Any ideas how to get my data back from the USB drive? And what went wrong...

In detailes:

I copied my data with:

```
sudo rsync -r --progress ./Files /media/usb
sudo rm -r ./Files
```

Now on /media/usb there weren't any files. /media/usb is FAT32

Comment: Can't tell what you did wrong unless you show us what you did.

Comment: I added details!

Comment: Next time use `--remove-source-files` and let `rsync` delete the successfully copied files for you

Comment: If you _unplug_ the USB stick do you have anything on `/media/usb`?